# Enforce blurry scaling on high dpi

Tags: windows-10, scaling, high-dpi

I have a 4K 15 inch screen set with scaling on 200% with the new Windows 10 display settings (not via the old Control Panel). Of course there are some old (and also recent unfortunately) applications that misbehave when scaling. Now I find that Windows 10 tries too hard to scale, so that text get's upscaled correctly, but icons and other images don't at all. See first screenshot of the program Eagle. Now sometimes windows does not try this, and just renders the application on 96dpi and then resizes it, resulting in a blurry but proportionally correct UI. See second screenshot of device manager. It's not so beautiful, but at least it's usable.

So my question is:
**How do I get Windows scale the application in the first screenshot as in the second screenshot?**

[image]
[image]

(Note: open the images on true size to see what I mean)

Comment: just out of extreme curiocity, what display?

Comment: Of my new dell XPS 15, no idea who actually manufactured the screen though.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the app and I think the best you can do is contact the EAGLE app developers and ask them to implement support for HiDPI screens. You will notice that apps like Google Chrome, Adobe Photoshop, Steam, etc also don't scale properly.

Your other option is to disable DPI scaling for those apps.

1. Right-click on the program exe file (not the shortcut) and click Properties.
2. Click the Compatibility tab.
3. Check the box labeled "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings".